# Memory Leak from NotificationManager

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I execute this code from an Activity onCreate. It creates a notification message. My question is:

Do i need to unregister the notification when the activity gets destroyed? I mean we passing a context there and as far as i know notifications stay  when an activity is destroyed, it might cause a memory leak. In the NotificatuonManagerCompat class context is being kept to variable.

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Picture Download")
    .setContentText("Download in progress")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);


int PROGRESS_MAX = 100;
int PROGRESS_CURRENT = 0;
mBuilder.setProgress(PROGRESS_MAX, PROGRESS_CURRENT, false);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build())
```

Comment: No need to worry, `NotificationManagerCompat` uses  `context.getApplicationContext()`. Also when notification notified it is not dependent on your `activity`.

Comment: @Omkar NotificationManagerCompat class holds a reference to context we are passing

Comment: Yes it does but it keeps application context, not activity.

Comment: @Omkar From the source code:    private NotificationManagerCompat(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

It keeps a reference from the original context

Comment: Ok, then try passing `getApplicationContext()` to `NotificationManagerCompact`.